# How to install Quill dev 2.0 with NPM, Webpacker, and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, webpack, quill

Having issues getting Quilljs Dev 2.0 working with my rails project. Vanilla Quilljs works just fine, but when I install quill-2.0-dev via npm, and import it in Webpacker, I get Unexpected token '!'

Errors in console:

[image]
[image]

app/javascript/packs/quill-editor.js

```
import Quill from 'quill-2.0-dev'
export default Quill;

window.onload = () => {

const quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    modules: {
        toolbar: {
            container: '#toolbar'
        }
    },
    placeholder: 'Compose a document...',
    theme: 'snow'
});
};
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
"@client-side-validations/client-side-validations": "^0.1.4",
"@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0-alpha",
"@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0-alpha",
"@rails/ujs": "^6.0.2-1",
"@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7",
"boxicons": "^2.0.4",
"i": "^0.3.6",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"npm": "^6.14.8",
"quill-2.0-dev": "^2.0.0-dev.3",
"quill-blot-formatter": "^1.0.5",
"quill-emoji": "^0.1.7",
"turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
```

},

***Update***

When I try it with the require keyword:

```
const Quill = require('quill-2.0-dev');
```

I get this error:
[image]

but as you can see, it's in my package.json (above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this step it may help

```rb
# Add package from yarn
yarn add quill-2.0-dev

# Import module in app/javascript/packs/application.js 

import Quill from 'quill-2.0-dev/core'
import Toolbar from 'quill-2.0-dev/modules/toolbar'
import Snow from 'quill-2.0-dev/themes/snow';
import Bold from 'quill-2.0-dev/formats/bold';
import Italic from 'quill-2.0-dev/formats/italic';
import Header from 'quill-2.0-dev/formats/header';

Quill.register({
  'modules/toolbar': Toolbar,
  'themes/snow': Snow,
  'formats/bold': Bold,
  'formats/italic': Italic,
  'formats/header': Header
});

# Init

window.onload = function() {
  var editor = new Quill('#editor', {
    modules: { toolbar: '#toolbar' },
    theme: 'snow'
  });
}

# In view

<div id="toolbar">
  <button class="ql-bold">Bold</button>
  <button class="ql-italic">Italic</button>
</div>

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

Flowing the [docs](https://quilljs.com/guides/adding-quill-to-your-build-pipeline/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion, however now I'm getting broken toolbar icons. Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/ePuOiyC

Comment: @Seth  Yeah, I see, is using ver `2.0-dev` is your requirement?

Comment: Ver 2.0-dev style is not compiled yet, so we cannot import it, or may we have run compile  by ourself

Comment: Using that version is not a requirement, but my client does want tables which are only available in ver 2.0 dev. For now, I'm moving on with Summernote which has tables built in.